# Align div in center

Tags: html, css

I want to align the element with the id `content` both horizontally and vertically in the center. I already tried to use `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` but both doesn't seem to work. I want to keep the absolute position because it will work as a popup window which should be displayed in the center.

```css
#field {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
        background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To the one who closed my question: It's about ABSOLUTE positioning, so the question dont have an answer on your link ;)

Comment: Setting the `display:flex` property on `#field`, along with `justify-content` and `align-items`, will work, even though it is using absolute positioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`justify-content` and `align-items` are for flexbox. You have to use `display: flexbox;`See example below:

```css
#field {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


}
#content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
        background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated Code with `position: absolute;`:**
You can keep `position: absolute;` and still flexbox the container. See below example:

```css
#field {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should work with `display: flex;` but I want to keep the absolute position so your code isn't going to work for my purpose. The div will be used as a popup window which should appear in the center. But still thank you very much! :) (Still upvoted)

Comment: @catmau5 Updated the answer. You can still use flexbox and keep it absolute positioned.